# How to get the list of the packages provided within a particular Linux distribution

Tags: package-management

Is it possible to know exactly what are the packages initially installed  in Linux Mint? After installing Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.1 64 bits, I have installed other packages that are in the official repositories but unfortunately I don't remember now which ones I have done. 
Now I am looking for a way to uninstall all the packages that were not initially installed by the distribution.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to know ahead of time what will be installed, or what has already been installed on a particular system. On Debian-based platforms, packages belonging to the [base system](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s3.7) will always be installed by default; they will be marked as "required" or "important". Different installers may or may not include additional packages, quietly or as a user option.

Comment: For example, a full graphical environment is usually selected by installing `task-xxx-desktop` which pulls in the rest of its packages via dependencies (where `xxx` could be e.g. `gnome`). Other distros have different standards and conventions; but since you ask about Mint, which is Debian-based, this should at least get you started (and hopefully inspire you to clarify your question).

Comment: To simply see what's installed, try `dpkg -l`.

Comment: The answer to this varies based on user (system installer) making choices ahead of time or during installation, so I'm not sure it can be answered as-is. Perhaps you could clarify some reasonable restrictions?

Comment: Also, there are a bunch of "other Linux distributions " so that could be narrowed down.

Comment: I narrowed the scope of the question in order to re-open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [this forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=247773) , the solution for linux mint distribution may be summarized as follows:

1. Get the file *filesystem.manifest* which can be found in the  *casper* folder  in the Live Session ISO. This file lists all the packages used to build the linux mint distribution.
2. Use in a terminal the command `dpkg-query -W > installedPackages` to list in the file *installedPackages* , all the  packages currently installed in the system.
3. Use the command `grep -Fxvf filesystem.manifest installedPackages > addedPackages` to list only the packages added by the system administrator.

We can also use in step 3 :`diff -y --suppress-common-lines filesystem.manifest installedPackages > comparePackages`

In a similar manner, one can easily imagine  a solution for other distributions. We have just to replace the step 1 as needed.

Answer (score 0):

For the RPM based distributions like Ret Hat, Fedora or CentOS, you can use the following command:

```
$ rpm -qa
```

For the DPKG based distributions like Ubuntu, **Mint** or Debian, you can use the command:

```
$ dpkg -l
```

You can also filter out the output list from those command piping (|) command as follows:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep python (if you are interested on python packages).
```

---

```
$ dpkg -l | grep python
```

Comment: This answers a different question, I think -- what packages are installed at the moment; not the default list (if any).

Comment: I think as pointed out by @JeffSchaller, that dpkg -l is not the answer to the question since it gives us the list of all the packages installed in the system ( the ones installed by the system administration in addition to the ones initially provided  by the distribution).

Comment: It's right that dpkg - l just give you the current packages but it will give you a good approach of what you have on top of the default packages for a distribution. The answer to this question is go to the website Linux distro and look for the release documentation for a particular version.

Answer (score 0):

you can do dpkg-query -l > installedPackages.txt
this creates a lit of all installed packages. but if you want to find out if a package is installed or not, you can do:

aptitude search packagename.. if the package is installed it would be marked as "ii"

Answer (score 0):

For a Debian or Debian based system (Ubuntu, Mint, etc) you can look at /var/log/apt/history.*

Of course, depending on how old your system is and the logging and log rotation set up you may or may not have complete logs.  Here's a snippet from one of mine...

```
Start-Date: 2017-05-26  20:08:30
Commandline: apt-get install calibre
Requested-By: myusername (1000)
Install: libqt5clucene5:amd64 (5.5.1-3build1, automatic), libqt5svg5:amd64 (5.5.1-2build1, automatic), libqt5test5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.2, automatic), libqt5help5:amd64 (5.5.1-3build1, automatic), python-cssutils:amd64 (1.0-4.1, automatic), python-cssselect:amd64 (0.9.1+git90c72b0-1, automatic), libpodofo0.9.3:amd64 (0.9.3-4, automatic), python-pyqt5.qtsvg:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4, automatic), python-pyparsing:amd64 (2.0.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), python-apsw:amd64 (3.8.11.1-r1-1build1, automatic), python-repoze.lru:amd64 (0.6-6, automatic), python-mechanize:amd64 (1:0.2.5-3, automatic), python-pyqt5.qtwebkit:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4, automatic), libchm1:amd64 (2:0.40a-3, automatic), calibre-bin:amd64 (2.55.0+dfsg-1, automatic), python-pyqt5:amd64 (5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4, automatic), python-dateutil:amd64 (2.4.2-1, automatic), calibre:amd64 (2.55.0+dfsg-1), libqt5designer5:amd64 (5.5.1-3build1, automatic), python-cherrypy3:amd64 (3.5.0-2build1, automatic), python-routes:amd64 (2.2-1ubuntu2, automatic), python-markdown:amd64 (2.6.6-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2017-05-26  20:09:30
```

Of course with any distribution you can spin up a new VM and see what is installed using `dpkg`, `rpm` etc. and get the default that way...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know the same thing on Ubuntu 22.04.3 and this must be close:

```
dpkg-query --status | perl -lane 'if(/^Package:/){$p=$F[1]}elsif(/^Priority:/){print "$p: $F[1]"}' | egrep required
```

based on the answer from [triplee](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/19240/tripleee)